# Google extension - chrome.action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that, when clicked, activates an 'on' badge and includes a CSS file to make the extension work. When I click on it again, it deactivates the extension (badgeText "" (no text), and removes the CSS). Everything works fine, except that I added a div when my extension is active, and I want it to also deactivate the extension after being clicked (badgeText "" (no text), and remove the CSS).

However, this isn't working, and an error occurs.
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'removeCSS')
at HTMLDivElement. (:13:22)"

My code :

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.action.setBadgeText({
    text: ''
  });
});

// When the user clicks on the extension action
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {
    // We retrieve the action badge to check if the extension is 'ON' or 'OFF'
    const prevState = await chrome.action.getBadgeText({ tabId: tab.id });
    // Next state will always be the opposite
    const nextState = prevState === 'ON' ? '' : 'ON';

    // Set the action badge to the next state
    await chrome.action.setBadgeText({
      tabId: tab.id,
      text: nextState
    });

    if (nextState === 'ON') {
      // Insert the CSS file when the user turns the extension on
      await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        func: getTitle,
        target: { tabId: tab.id }
      });

      await chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
        files: ['focus-mode.css'],
        target: { tabId: tab.id }
      });

    } else if (nextState === '') {
      // Remove the CSS file when the user turns the extension off
      await chrome.scripting.removeCSS({
        files: ['focus-mode.css'],
        target: { tabId: tab.id }
      });
    }
});

function getTitle() {
  // Créez une div
  var exitDiv = document.createElement('div');
  exitDiv.textContent = "Exit Extension";
  exitDiv.classList.add('exit-button');

  // Ajoutez la div au corps du document
  document.body.appendChild(exitDiv);

  // Gérez l'événement de clic sur la div
  exitDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('OFF extension');
    chrome.scripting.removeCSS({
      files: ['focus-mode.css']
    });

    chrome.action.setBadgeText({
      text: 'OFF'
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Add "scripting" to "permissions" and reload the extension.

Comment: Yes, I have already added it because it works well in `chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {});`

My manifest.json include
`"permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab"]`

Comment: The error comes from getTitle function which you inject into the tab, so it runs in the context of a content script, which can't use most of `chrome` namespace. You need to split the code and call chrome.scripting outside of getTitle.

Comment: Okay, but how should I proceed, please?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, with

`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse)`
and `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'updateBadge', text: 'OFF' });`